# MySQL: Create table clone that updates columns with original

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Basically, what I need is a `newtable` that's exact clone of `oldtable`.
`newtable` would contain products that await approval, and `oldtable` would contain approved products that anyone can see.
Now my question is: Is it possible for `newtable` to update its structure to match `oldtable` when I make a change, like add a new column?
 Or do I need to update both tables everytime? 
 I'm trying to cut down on migrations. PHP/Laravel for school project.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just set a column value for example :`approved` to true if a product is approved, this is also more efficient than copying and updating everything twice.

Comment: @Aless55 Yes, that's how I initially wanted to do it, but I'm worried that doing it like that, I'm opening that table for spam and bad data, because users are also able to submit products. Now, if I have two tables, I have a clean viable table for everyone to see, and one table that can always be safely emptied.

Comment: I see where you are coming from but I would just use strong validation and normally you would build in some restriction for people issuing products. In production you will never empty the table because even if some spam is present many products waiting for approval are not spam. 
Therefore I think that the "spam" problem should have a diffrent solution than the one you are looking for.
You could for example include some constraints that new users will have to verify their email + maybe phone number or address and limit not verified users or certain user groups to XY new products per week.

Comment: @Aless55 I see, strong validation and spam limitation it is. Thanks for your opinion on this matter. It really helps out talking to others. People here can sometimes be very unwelcoming to beginners.